# Flutter is not recognized as internal or external command after run without debugging

Tags: flutter, flutter-run, flutter-debug

[image]

This problem occurs when i try to run application after doing some changes to the code. I try to run using vscode command `Run Without Debugging` and this problem occurs. It works when i delete sdk folder and download it again. But it is not the right way as i should download new SDK every time i run app

(Also after clicking run without debugging, `flutter is not be recognized as internal or external command` will be shown in terminal, i don't know why but it is really weird,even though i added path variable)

Below is **log output** of vscode.

```
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for SDKs...
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info] Environment PATH:
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS\system32
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     D:\Git\cmd
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\nodejs\
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     D:\MPLab\MPLAB C32 Suite\bin
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     D:\flutter\bin
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Roaming\npm
[12:51:44 PM] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info] Found Flutter project at C:\Users\neyyu\Desktop\first_flutter_project:
            Mobile? true
            Web? false
            Create Trigger? false
            Flutter Repo? false
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for flutter.bat
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Looking for flutter.bat in:
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\Desktop\first_flutter_project
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\Desktop\first_flutter_project\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         D:\flutter\bin\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\Desktop\first_flutter_project\.flutter
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\Desktop\first_flutter_project\.flutter\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\Desktop\first_flutter_project\vendor\flutter
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\Desktop\first_flutter_project\vendor\flutter\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         D:\Git\cmd
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         D:\Git\cmd\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         D:\MPLab\MPLAB C32 Suite\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         D:\flutter\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Roaming\npm
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path undefined for flutter.bat
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for dart.exe
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Looking for dart.exe in:
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         D:\Git\cmd
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         D:\Git\cmd\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         D:\MPLab\MPLAB C32 Suite\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         D:\flutter\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Roaming\npm
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\neyyu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[12:51:51 PM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path undefined for dart.exe
```

Comment: Did you add the flutter binary in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: yes i did add like this, "D:\flutter\bin"

Comment: this problem does not occur when creating app using "flutter run" but it happens when i try to run app after building

Comment: Did you relaunch your VSCode? VSCode terminal might not have updated with the latest version of your PATH environment variable.

Comment: yes i did, i even restarted pc multiple times but same thing happens each time

Comment: it seems like flutter.bat file is removed autmatically when i try to run app again

Comment: It might have to do with your firewall or your anti virus